# Writing a Test Plan for Requirements without Domain Knowledge

Tags: requirements

I'm writing up a test plan to verfy that software, which I didn't write, satisfies a bunch requirements.

What advice do you have? Has anyone been in this situation before? I reach out for help from the developer who wrote the code and the requirements expert, but getting a lot of their time is tough.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the first thing is to figure out what each requirement means for end-users.

Then I'd start with writing several tests (without much details) against each requirement you have. When there is some basic stuff, try to group it into several sections.

Don't forget to make such checks as Antivirus scan, install/uninstall (if available), all files including documentation should be in place, try to make some negative cases (application shouldn't crash if user made a typo at input).

Then try to formalize tests: what exact you do and what exact you check.

Write it in well-readable document, and send to developer, requirement expert and probably some others for review and feedback. That would probably be a good start.